# Help with Calculus Newton's Method

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Alright So I have kind of an interesting question involving Newton's method and have been at this for quite some time, and have come up with that it is not possible. I would like some input to if this is correct or not.

Here is the question:

> Find an approximate solution, accurate to the nearest $0.0001$, using
>   Newton’s method, to the equation
>
> $$e^{-x^2}=x$$
>
> Use an initial guess of  and submit your solution with the following
>   format – completing each cell until you stop.

Any insight is appreciated. I have been using excel to obtain my answer. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Newton's method finds zeroes of a given function; use it on $f(x) = e^{x^2}-x$.

Comment: but, $e^{x^2} > x$ for all $x.$

Comment: Using that formula it takes n to infinity to get a small enough error.

Comment: no solution exists, so Newton's method will never converge

Comment: Shoot, I am sorry I forgot to place the negative infront of the x^2, I corrected in the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newton's method uses the iteration

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Here, the function is $$f(x)=e^{-x^2}-x$$ and the derivate is $$f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}-1$$

Start, for example, with $x_0=0$

PARI gives the following solution :

```
 ? x=0;for(j=1,7,x=x-(exp(-x^2)-x)/(-2*x*exp(-x^2)-1);print(j,"  ",x))
  1  1.000000000000000000000000000
  2  0.6358246728512563352125216145
  3  0.6529371688445918014075897750
  4  0.6529186404370339013079025757
  5  0.6529186404192047155350972802
  6  0.6529186404192047155350807674
  7  0.6529186404192047155350807674
```

Comment: I think the OP changed the problem slightly.

Comment: Yes I did, I am very sorry, I forgot the negative

Comment: When you run that equation you have through excel though it never will converge. Am I right about this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it's operator precedence - spreadsheets treat $-x^2$ as $(-x)^2$ you just need to add brackets to correct for this so replace $-x^2$ by $-(x^2)$ and everything will work.

the formula `(A2 =) A1-( EXP(-(A1^2))-A1)/(-2*A1*EXP(-(A1^2))-1)`

does converge but `A1-( EXP(-A1^2)-A1)/(-2*A1*EXP(-A1^2)-1)`

does not. check out the formula `=-1^2`, spreadsheets give the answer as +1

Comment: THIS WAS MY PROBLEM!!! thanks so much. lol I feel dumb

Comment: I think it is the spreadsheets that are dumb, I don't understand why they behave like that.